# Invalid session for the user, session is expired

Tags: amazon-cognito

I created a user on Amazon Cognito using a temporary password. when I logged in using a temporary password I am getting a challenge session token that is having validity less than 5 minutes. is it possible to increase the time? after 5 minutes if is submit the password reset request with that session I am getting Invalid session for the user, session is expired.

Answer (score 0):

No, the whole point of that short time is to boost security. Think of it as an OTP sent to you that you have to verify quickly. Is there any particular reason you want this time extended? 5 minutes is more than enough time to set a new password with the forced password change request.

Comment: what is the timeout for the session? is this fixed or configurable?

Comment: @SudoCoder For the default implementation I don't believe there is any way to change the timeout. But you can implement your own change password flow using the cognito APIs and custom scripts.